# Autocomplete dropdown without jQuery with links

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete, html-datalist

I'm trying to use an auto complete dropdown menu using the HTML5 datalist attribute, without JQuery. But I want each suggestion, when selected, goes to an specific link (or when pressed enter, goes to the first suggestion).

What I have right now is:

```
<form action="www.site.com/search?q=" method="get">

 <input name="q" type="text" id="txtAutoComplete" list="languageList"/>

  <datalist id="languageList">

   <option value="OPTION1" />
   <option value="OPTION2" />

  </datalist>

</form>
```

In this case, it performs a search in the site. I want each option to open a specific link, OR to use **value** at the end of the link http://www.hitsebeats.ninja/search/label/**VALUE_HERE**, which goes to the correct label in Blogger. In this last case, I thought about adding the event `onclick`:

```
<datalist id="languageList" onclick='location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;>

    <option value='http://www.hitsebeats.ninja/search/label/OPTION1'>
    OPTION1
    </option>

</datalist>
```

But no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding another answer after OP feedback in the comments. This should redirect only if the typed option exists in the datalist.

```
<script>
    function redirect(value) {
        var options = document.getElementById("languageList").options;

        for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            if (options[i].value == value)
                window.location='http://www.example.com/' + value;
        };
    }
</script>
<form action="http://www.example.com/search?q=" method="get">
  <input name="q" type="text" id="txtAutoComplete" list="languageList" onchange="redirect(this.value)" />

  <datalist id="languageList">
    <option value='OPTION1'>OPTION1</option>
    <option value='OPTION2'>OPTION2</option>
  </datalist>
</form>
```

---

## First Attempt

Using `oninput` on the input element you can change the location depending on what option you choose.

```
<form action="http://www.example.com/search?q=" method="get">
  <input name="q" type="text" id="txtAutoComplete" list="languageList" onchange="window.location='http://www.example.com/' + this.value" />

  <datalist id="languageList">
    <option value='OPTION1'>OPTION1</option>
    <option value='OPTION2'>OPTION2</option>
  </datalist>
</form>
```

Tell me if it is what you expected or not.

Comment: The idea looks good, but this makes any letter typed trigger `oninput`, which doesn't give enough time to the user to select and option or to finish typing.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos Yes, forgot that... Then onchange is your best bet. But it will only trigger when you lose focus on the input element (click away)

Comment: Pierre, I was just going to write it.Thanks for the initial help. I managed it changing oninput for onchange. It solved everything. But another trouble appeared. If users doesn't select an option, what they typed will go over the link, and it cannot happen. Labels are case sensitive, and should be exactly like the **value**. Is there anyway to block what users typed, and only accept what is on the list?

Comment: Writing some JS code to check if the typed word in the the datalist is a possibility. So you redirect only if it is in there.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos I added another code block that does what I said in the comment just above.

Comment: That's jut great! Thanks for what you've helped until now. But there was a little mistake there, with the <form>. I removed it because it was triggering the search of the site. 

It worked. But now, I want to use that form below in a button, so the user can search in if there wasn't any result matched on the list. Basically the "value" of the input should go after "/search?q=". How can I do it?

You can check how it is working now on www.hitsebeats.ninja. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106023/discussion-between-pierre-c-and-henrique-barcelos).

Answer (score 0):

So just you know, datalist doesn't have selected events, it's not a user control. But you can listen to the input change event and them use it to change the url.

Comment: Ok, now that I know datalist does not suport select, could you give a light to the next step on how to listen to the input change event?